# Gradle sync failed: A problem occurred configuring project ':lib'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I am trying to build one project in android studio but its always fails with error called

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:38)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:161)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:158)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.wrapException(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:96)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:68)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$3.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:443)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration$3.execute(DefaultConfiguration.java:436)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:436)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveToStateOrLater(DefaultConfiguration.java:411)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:403)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.collectArtifacts(DependencyManager.java:484)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveConfiguration(DependencyManager.java:354)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:263)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.DependencyManager.resolveDependencies(DependencyManager.java:166)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.resolveDependencies(TaskManager.java:375)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createVariantData$3(VariantManager.java:607)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantData(VariantManager.java:603)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createVariantDataForProductFlavors(VariantManager.java:793)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.populateVariantDataList(VariantManager.java:469)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:263)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:601)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:596)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:526)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:522)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    ... 67 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':lib'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:94)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:89)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.doConfigure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:76)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.access$000(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:53)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$1.execute(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:628)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.evaluateProjectAndDiscoverTasks(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:32)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectAccessListener.beforeResolvingProjectDependency(DefaultProjectAccessListener.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dependencies.DefaultProjectDependency.beforeResolved(DefaultProjectDependency.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(ProjectIvyDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.createDependencyDescriptor(DefaultDependencyDescriptorFactory.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.addDependencies(DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.dependencies.DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.addDependencyDescriptors(DefaultDependenciesToModuleDescriptorConverter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.moduleconverter.DefaultConfigurationComponentMetaDataBuilder.addConfigurations(DefaultConfigurationComponentMetaDataBuilder.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.toRootComponentMetaData(DefaultConfiguration.java:682)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$DefaultResolveContextToComponentResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:138)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:93)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:85)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:25)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:187)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:170)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:129)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:191)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:56)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolveGraph(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:66)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getPlatformVersion(NdkHandler.java:145)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.supports64Bits(NdkHandler.java:291)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.ndk.NdkHandler.getSupportedAbis(NdkHandler.java:354)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.create(ExternalNativeJsonGenerator.java:571)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.TaskManager.createExternalNativeBuildJsonGenerators(TaskManager.java:1241)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager.lambda$createTasksForVariantData$11(LibraryTaskManager.java:240)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.LibraryTaskManager.createTasksForVariantData(LibraryTaskManager.java:235)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createTasksForVariantData(VariantManager.java:460)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.lambda$createAndroidTasks$1(VariantManager.java:282)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.VariantManager.createAndroidTasks(VariantManager.java:278)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createAndroidTasks$6(BasePlugin.java:601)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:596)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$null$4(BasePlugin.java:526)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder.record(ThreadRecorder.java:81)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.lambda$createTasks$5(BasePlugin.java:522)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:82)
    ... 135 more
```

My Project level gradle file is like below

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.6.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App Gradle file is like this

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.iz.plus2'
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 16
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.1'
        android {
            defaultConfig {
                ndk {
                    abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
                }
            }
        }
    }
//    lintOptions {
//        abortOnError false
//    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility 1.8
        targetCompatibility 1.8
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(path: ':lib')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'org.jdeferred:jdeferred-android-aar:1.2.4'
    compile 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.4'
}
```

and sub module project lib gradle file is like below

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.1'
        externalNativeBuild {
            ndkBuild {
                abiFilters "armeabi", "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path file("src/main/jni/Android.mk")
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    //    compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
    compile files('src/main/libs/android-art-interpret-3.0.0.jar')
}
```

I have tried all possible way like invalidate cache etc but I am unable to solve the issue. I am trying from last two hours and still not able to solve it. Let me know if someone have faced similar issue or have idea about the issue and can help me for solve it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check `local.properties`

```
ndk.dir=E\:\\Android\\local\\Android\\Sdk\\ndk\\21.3.6528147
sdk.dir=E\:\\Android\\local\\Android\\Sdk
```

are correct,

Answer (score 0):

In your project level `build.gradle`,

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
    ...
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

In your app level `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api project(':lib')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'org.jdeferred:jdeferred-android-aar:1.2.4'
    implementation 'org.osmdroid:osmdroid-android:5.6.4'
}
```

Move your libs folder from `$library$/src/main/libs` to `$library$/libs`, then in your library sub module `build.gradle` file:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation files('libs/android-art-interpret-3.0.0.jar')
}
```

Then sync your project. Hope it helps!